# 2015 BlackBerry OS 7.0 development

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I'm interested in developing a Telegram app for the Blackberry os 7. Yeah, the old one. 
So, can I still develop, deploy and why not, release on BB OS7, or it's not possible any more.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is really a Stack Overflow question, but yes. You can still dev for it. You'll just struggle a bit to find support for it, and libraries will not have been updated in a long time.